# Generate a random number for a sql record in an aspx vb.net page per session

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)



            If (Not IsPostBack) Then
                Session("CurrentItemID") = 0
                SqlDataSource1.Insert()

                ASPxFormLayout1.DataBind()



            End If
        End Sub
```

I need to create a random record instead of starting from 0.  The reason I need this done is it fine for one user to use the web form, but when multiple users do, then the value is the same and they create duplicate records.  I need to have each user generate their own unique record number for their session.

This is the code where the record is written, with an increment.

```
 SqlDataSource1.Update()

            If e.Parameter = "finish" Then
                Session("CurrentItemID") = CInt(Fix(Session("CurrentItemID"))) + 1
                SqlDataSource1.Insert()
            End If
        End If
        ASPxFormLayout1.DataBind()
```

Comment: You could use a GUID, Globally Unique IDentifier.

Comment: +1 for using a GUID, especially because you're bound to run into concurrency problems messing with instance numbers that increment. Either that, or have an autoincremented ID field in the DB (or a sequence) and get it back after insert. But GUID would be my choice.

Comment: I am a Noob, so could you help me with the code here?    Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: Solution worked.